# Can choose Android Studio kotlin version?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am new in a kotlin . any one know how can i choose my build kotlin version ? is it impossible to change it ? if yes , how should do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kotlin version is specified in project level `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.0'
    //.....
```